# The argument type 'String? Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, dart-null-safety

I am trying to setup password and email validation and I am getting the error above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error above is in the main.dart code and has been bolded in the code.

validator.dart code

```
enum FormType { login, register }

class EmailValidator {
  static String? validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? "Email can't be empty" : null;
  }
}

class PasswordValidator {
  static String? validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? "Password can't be empty" : null;
  }
}
```

main.dart code

```
List<Widget>buildInputs() {
        return [
          TextFormField(
            validator: **EmailValidator.validate**,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: **PasswordValidator.validate**,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
            obscureText: true,
            onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
          ),
        ];
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check `validator` it returns a nullable String.

> `{String? Function(String?)? validator}`

You can convert your validators like

```dart
class EmailValidator {
  static String? validate(String? value) {
    return value==null ||  value.isEmpty ? "Email can't be empty" : null;
  }
}

class PasswordValidator {
  static String? validate(String? value) {
    return value==null ||value.isEmpty ? "Password can't be empty" : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can check more about [validation-logic](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation#2-add-a-textformfield-with-validation-logic)

Answer (score 1):

Your `validate` functions accept strictly non-null parameters. Change your function signature to `static String? validate(String? value)` (note the question mark after the second `String`) and it'll match the required signature.

Comment: I have already tried that and it gives an error on IsEmpty saying: The property 'isEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

Answer (score 0):

The validator returns a null when all conditions are met, so you should handle that like this

```
static String? validateMobile(String? value) {
  //Indian Mobile number are of 10 digit only
    if (value!.length != 10) {
      return 'Mobile Number must be of 10 digit';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```